# How to Add a specific number at the end of merging workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that use to merge all the raw data's found in the same folder(Group 1, Group 2, ... Group 15, Group 16), using the code below :

```
Sub MergeFiles()
Dim Path, Filename As String, group As Long
group = 1
Path = "C:\Users\calin.lencar\Desktop\DT Project\Project Holiday Group Raw 
Data\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.csv")

Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> "Digital Tracking Panel KPIs v1"
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
  LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("O2", Cells(LastRow, "O")).Value = group
  Range("A2:X" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(21).Activate
  Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Workbooks(Filename).Close

Filename = Dir()
group = group + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Files have been copied successfully"
End Sub
```

I am trying to add in the column "O:O" of each file the group number. The problem is that it opens them alphabetically: "Group 1, Group 10, Group 11... Group 2, Group 3..." but the group counter still goes : 1, 2, 3...

Could you please help me, I need the group counter to match the number in the file's name(maybe populate O:O with the first number it encounters?) or make excel open the files after explorer name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your files contain `Group 1` `Group 2` etc. in the file name or tab or wherever?

Comment: Yes, they are named exactly "Group 1 5.12.2017" ; "Group 2 5.12.2017" ; "Group 3 5.12.2017"... "Group 15 5.12.2017".

Comment: Then why don't you just extract it from the file name instead of using a counter.

Comment: Yes I was looking into this as well, just made a function with regEx that seems to work, i'll post as an answer to see if it's concrete.

Comment: Instead of using regEx just split the string using the space as the delimeter and use the first two parts of the array.

Comment: Why not Trim(Left(filename,8))  ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because Dir() just goes to the next alphabetical file in the directory. You could try putting a leading zero into the filenames like "Group 01, Group 02, ..."

Comment: yes that could be a workaround, thanks I haven't thought about that xD

Answer (score 1):

This is how it `Dir()` works - it takes the next file alphabetically. Many programs and functions follow this logic actually. [Dir() MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)

However, if you have all the files from 1 to 15 and they are with the same names, you may try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim firstPart   As String
    Dim i           As Long

    firstPart = "Group "

    For i = 1 To 15
        Debug.Print firstPart & i & ".xlsx"
        'now open this file
    Next i

End Sub
```

It will work. Consider checking whether the file `Group 7.xlsx` exists, before openning it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a function to get the first number(first 1 or 2 digits) and add them in the column that I needed.

```
Function Number(txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 .Pattern = "\d{1,2}"
Number = .Execute(txt)(0)
End With
End Function

Sub MergeFiles()
Dim Path, Filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\calin.lencar\Desktop\DT Project\Project Holiday Group Raw 
Data\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.csv")

Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> "Digital Tracking Panel KPIs v1"
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
  LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("O2", Cells(LastRow, "O")).Value = Number(Filename)
  Range("A2:X" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(21).Activate
  Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Workbooks(Filename).Close
  Filename = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox "Files have been copied successfully"
End Sub
```